# C++/CLI wrapper for C++ native dlls

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dll, c++-cli

I have native C++ dlls that I need to use in our group's new C# programs. I wanna create C++/CLI wrappers for native C++ dlls, so as to be able to import and compile them in C#.

What I need to know is how to load the dll file in the wrapper source file at the first place. Exactly the same thing that #using <...> does for MSIL, but for loading native C++ dlls.

And also, how will the objects and namespaces inside the dll become accessible then (synatically)?

**EDIT:**

I use

```
class __declspec(dllexport) radar
{
    // declarations and definitions
    ...
};
```

to export my radar class from my radar.dll, and need to import it in a VC++(CLI) program like this: `__declspec(dllimport) public class radar;` so as to conduct it's definition into C#, but definitely I can't see radar in C#, because its not defined public in VC++(CLI). Even when I wanna use native dll's objects in VC++ dll's code, like `radar pos1();` I get:

`error C2512: 'radar' : no appropriate default constructor available`

How can do this, having just the radar declaration at hand?

**END EDIT.**

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you need to create a C++/CLI wrapper?  is there a reason not to just call the native DLL's using PInvoke from C#?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446536.aspx

Answer (score 3):

It is automatic, you don't do this yourself.  You specify the native DLL import libraries (.lib) in the linker settings for the C++/CLI project, Additional Dependencies setting.  The linker links in a reference to the DLL name into the C++/CLI assembly.  As soon as the C# code uses any of the managed types in the C++/CLI assembly, the CLR loads the assembly.  Windows notices the native DLL references in the DLL and automatically loads them.

This can only come to a good end if Windows can actually find the native DLLs at runtime.  Copy them into the build folder of the EXE project.  That's awkward, you can do it with a post-build event or by adding them to the C# project with their Copy to Output Directory property set to true.

Comment: ok, I think the method I'd prefer is at this time is explicit linking. I wanna use `LoadLibrary()` and `GetProcAddress()` for function access, but I also have lots of classes in my DLL. How do I import classes into my program?

Comment: "Lots of classes" makes this horribly impractical.  You could write a COM server to make explicit linking feasible.

Comment: thus the methods we talked about so far are almost the only existing ones when talking about unmanaged dlls, right? And I should give this method up and write them as COM?

Comment: Just make sure the DLL is in a place where Windows can find it.

Comment: Hans, my main obsession is the classes, is it possible to import the class declaration as a whole from the DLL file, or the only way is to import a class's functions one by one, just like the usual samples all over the net? Or should I delegate it to my friends to use platform invoke?